# Sum all numbers in array function not returning the sum

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that sum all numbers in an array! I am new to JavaScript and in need of someone pointing me in the right direction!

```
function sum(arr) {

    var i = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        return index += arr[i];
    }
}

sum([1, 2, 3]); //6
```

Comment: `return` exits the function, not the loop .. also, you're adding to `index` rather than `i`, and using `i` as the `index` which is stcuk at `0`

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** for that:

```js
function getSum(ary){
  return ary.reduce(function(sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(getSum([0, 1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have to write as a function that uses one parameter (arr - an array of integers)

Comment: @MarioGomez then just put the code in a function. This is the correct answer

Comment: "this is the correct answer" ... yes, except it does not show where the original code went wrong, there's no value to simply giving an answer that uses `reduce` without at least some explanation of why the code in the question is failing - besides, this is actually **NOT** the best use of reduce anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

to illustrate where your code is wrong

```
function sum(arr) {
    var i = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        return index += arr[i]; // this will return from your function in the first iteration
    }
}
```

as the comment says, `return` will exit your function in the first iteration

also, you're adding to `index`, which is supposed to be the  index into the array, you want to add to `i`, and then `return i` after the loop

so, the code should be

```
function sum(arr) {
    var i = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        i += arr[index];
    }

    return i;
}
```

As another answer pointed out, a probably better alternative is to use array reduce function - however the code in that answer is not the "best" usage of reduce

```
function getSum(ary){
    return ary.reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    }, 0);
}
```

can actually be written

```
function getSum(ary){
    return ary.reduce(function(sum, value) {
        return sum + value;
    });
}
```

This uses one less iteration, because there is no "initial value", and the first iteration adds index 0 and 1 together

Sure, it's not going to make a performance difference, but why not use built-in functions properly :p

Comment: Thanks @jaromanda x !! I am begginer in Javascript! Your explanation makes a lot sense !

Comment: *"but why not use built-in functions properly"* It is not *improper* to use the function as I have. It came directly from MDN, by the way.

Comment: sorry, "improperly" was too harsh @ScottMarcus - also, a later example `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );` shows how without an initial value :p

Answer (score 1):

Lots of basic issues with the code.

You need a separate variable to accumulate the result in. Your code is writing into the index variable of a for loop. This is wrong for a number of reasons.

You also return after the first iteration of the loop.

Assuming you want to use a for loop (which is not the least amount of code),

```
function sum(arr) {    
  var sum = 0;
  for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    sum += arr[index];
  }    
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Sum(arr) {

   var sum = 0;

   for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
       sum += arr[index];
   }
   return index;

}

Sum([1, 2, 3]); //6
```

Return immediately exits a function. Your code will never sum values. What is 'i' in your code!?! And what index do!?

Comment: `Anyway, Use upper case for first character of function name` **no** - the "convention" is to use upper case for a "class" name ...  i.e a function that is supposed to be called with the `new` keyword - and it's only a convention

Comment: Maybe you are right, i'm C programmer, so function means something else in my pov.

Comment: does `C` have a case convention for functions? I know it's not a "rule", considering the entry point for `C` programs is `main` not `Main` :p

Comment: int Sum(List<int> numbers){...}

Comment: Something like this.

Comment: I have to downvote your answer because you don't really explain it well, your formatting is bad (select your code and click the `{}` button) and your last sentence isn't even a good suggestion. (For instance, _"Return stops all things in a function"_ doesn't really explain it. So it stops it... and then what? _"Return immediately exits a function"_ is a better explanation.) If you can clean your answer up a bit I'll upvote :)

Comment: @Clonkex i answer this question with my phone :) excuse me if its not a good one...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get your function to work:

```
  function sum(arr) {
     // this is the variable we're going to add our numbers onto
     var acc = 0;

     for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        // don't return here, return is used to return from a function
        acc += arr[index];
     }
     // after adding all numbers, return the sum
     return acc
   }

   sum([1, 2, 3]); //6
```

But there are built in ways to do this, like Array.reduce() like Scott Marcus mentioned.